# Googles Map API v3 - Invalid Calling Object

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I recently we have upgraded to IE10 from IE7. We are receiving error Invalid Calling Object at below 2nd line of code (if (init < markers.length)).

```
function loadMarkers() {
if (init < markers.length) {
    var max = Math.min(init + 10, markers.length);
    while (init < max) {
        var lat = parseFloat(markers[init].getAttribute("lat"));
        var lng = parseFloat(markers[init].getAttribute("lng"));
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var html = markers[init].getAttribute("html");
        var propType = markers[init].getAttribute("propType");

        switch (propType) {
            case '1':
                //markerColor = "Red";
                markerColor = "FF0000";
                break;
            case '2':
                //markerColor = "Yellow";
                markerColor = "FFFF00";
                break;
            case '3':
                //markerColor = "Green";
                markerColor = "00FFBF";
                break;
            case '4':
                //markerColor = "White";
                markerColor = "FFFFFF";
                break;
            default:
                //markerColor = "Red";
                markerColor = "FF0000";
        }
        var marker = createMarker(point, html, init + 1, markerColor);
        markerArray.push(marker);
        if (init == 0) {
            map.setCenter(marker.position, 13);
        }
        $("#results").append("<li onclick='selectMarker(" + init + ")'>" + html.substring(html.indexOf(">", html.indexOf(">", html.indexOf(">") + 1) + 1) + 1, html.indexOf("</a>") - 4) + "</li>");
        init = init + 1;
        $("#load").css({
            'display': 'block'
        });
        $("#load").html("<b>Loading " + init + " of " + (markers.length) + "</b>");
    }
    if (init % 50 == 0) {
        showAll();
    }
    window.setTimeout(loadMarkers, 50);
}
if (init >= markers.length) {
    showAll();
    $("#load").css({
        'display': 'none'
    });
}
```

}

I am new to this and need your help to resolve this issue
Kindly help me.

Comment: How are init and markers defined?  How is loadMarkers() called?

Comment: These variables defined like this var init = 0;
var markers;

Comment: We are calling html javascript using peoplecode(peoplesoft)

Answer (score 1):

You declare markers as `var markers;` but then assume markers has length:

```
if (init < markers.length)
```

markers may not be an array because it's not defined as such.  You should define it as an array:

```
var markers = [];
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you guidance. I defined marker as array but it dint work. So I have taken 2 different variables and was able to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your guidance. I defined markers as an array and it was not working. So I have used array variable and it works fine now.

```
var yy = [];
```

var xx = markers.length;
yy = markers[init];